# Android - Design a fragment in view

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a `fragment_home.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".fragments.HomeFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="home page" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="lower text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When adding anything else to the view, nothing else shows. only the first text view shows.

[image]

My `HomeFragement.kotlin` file being like so (all boilerplate stuff nothing new)

```
package com.example.myapp.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.example.myapp.R

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
}

companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
        HomeFragment().apply {
            
        }
}
}
```

Comment: set `TextView` height to `wrap_content`

Comment: your home_page textView height is set to match parent. The second textView is generated below it, which is "below" the screen